Python: Import from parent directory from inside a sub-directory
I have the following folder structure:
T1
|_ /foo
      |_ /blah
            |_ file1.py
      |_ /some
            |_ file2.py
|_ /api
      |_ root_file.py

T1 is my parent directory. Below are the contents of each file.
In T1/foo/blah/file1.py:
##file1.py
from some.file2 import hello

def blah_blah():
   hello("John") 

In T1/foo/some/file2.py:
##file2.py
def hello(name):
  print(f"Hello from some {name}")

In T1/api/root_file.py
##root_file.py
from ..foo.blah.file1 import blah_blah

blah_blah()

But running the script api/root_file.py throws below error:
from ..foo.blah.file1 import blah_blah
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

If I move the root_file.py file from outside of /api folder, and change the import statement like so: from foo.blah.file1 import blah_blah, this works. How do I get the imports working from inside the /api folder, in this case? Is there a clean way to do this using absolute paths or even relative paths and without using  sys.path() or sys.insert() or the like?
